# Element not interactable while click() function is used in input type radio

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

Input with type="radio" is not clickable. How to select the different radio button inputs using selenium and beautiful soup. Thanks in advance.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'E:/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
htmlSource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
statement = soup.select('label:contains("Statement")')[0].input
print(statement)
statement.click()
```

Output:

```
<input name="" type="radio" value="Statement"/>
```

However statement.click() gives error:

```
statement.click()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

**P.S I've tried using xPath as well.**

```
statement = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@value=\'Statement\']')
print(statement)
statement.click()
```

Output:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="de0080d0898646c8f0053c8b2cbb1707", element="a426e341-f88c-4574-a831-5386a50cdd68")>
```

statement.click() gives follwing error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Comment: You can't even imagine to click on an element with the help of bs4. You should share the url and only possible to click and to solve clickable problem with selenium only here

Comment: Can you post the html of parent element of the input element which binds the input element.

Answer (score 0):

Beautifulsoup just allows you to view the data, it doesn't allow interaction -  so the click function wouldn't work no matter which element you tried.

For the selenium error, there are several possible reasons and potential solutions that are suggested in [this edureka thread](https://www.edureka.co/community/55217/resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-selenium-webdriver). I cannot pinpoint which of them might apply to your case without the actual link you're scraping from, but hopefully you'll find something helpful there.